# How to display a collection of blank form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I understand how to display a collection of a form field, but how do I display a blank to create the form empty?
I want to do is a form where "Anagrafic" has a one-to-many relationship with "MailTelCont."
A "Anagrafic" can insert more than one contact (email, phone, fax, etc.)..

```
->add('mailTelContacts', 'collection', array('type' => new MailTelContType(), 
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => true
            ))
```

my template:

```
{{ form_row(form3.mailTelContacts) }}
```

when I view the blank form this field is not displayed!

Comment: Symfony is a "bear" to learn. I've been melting my brain for months trying to get half-way decent with it. It's tough. And it's constantly changing. I can't wait for 2.3, then they will keep backwards compatibility "at all costs" until symfony3. I know this doesn't answer your question, but I had to vent. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this:

---

[image: Display a collection of form]

---

You need to use prototypes, what you are looking for is in the cookbook:

[How to embed a collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Pay special attention to [allowing new tags with the prototype](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype).

### EDIT

```
How can I have an empty field when loading the page?
```

Simply add your equivalent of `addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);` at the end of your jQuery script so that a line is automatically added at the loading of your page.

This would give:

```java
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // ...

    // Add empty form on page loading
    addTagForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
});
```

Comment: You'd just have to twick the javascript so that one empty field is displayed when you load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty dummy object at your createForm() call

```
$this->createForm(new CustomFormType(),$dummy);
```

What happens if you set `by_reference` to false?